# easyui "Object doesn't support this property or method" in ie 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-easyui

Hello I am using easyui in my web based application. It works fine chrome and firefox but in IE it gives me "Object doesn't support this property or method" error for easyui .window('open') method. The code is below: Thanks..

EDIT: I am including jquery after easyui library. Can this cause the problem?

```
 function init() {

                           var mesaj_text="<div style='margin-top:20px'>
<label style='font-size:13px;margin-left:55px'>Harita Yükleniyor</label><br> "; 
                            $("#mesajWindow").html(mesaj_text);
                            $("#mesajWindow").window("open"); //this is the line giving error


 //.........code continues//
```

Comment: well, `$.fn` doesn't have a `window` method. that's why the error is occuring. Are you sure *easyui* adds a `window` method to `$.fn`? are you sure *easyui* is included on the page after the jquery that currently owns `$`?

Comment: Yes I am sure eayui adds window method and I am including those easyui libraries. I think IE causes the problem..

Comment: This is the easyui doc. about window method: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/window.php

Comment: How would IE cause `$.fn.window` to be undefined where it wouldn't be in another browser, other than the library not loading in IE, or a syntax error occurring prior to this? The error is not related to the code you have posted. It's likely due to either where init is executed, or how/where the library is included. Figure out why the easyui plugin isn't being applied to jquery.

Comment: *"I am including jquery after easyui library. Can this cause the problem?"* Yes... That would make it not work in all browsers, not just IE.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B :)when I change including sequence it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was including jquery library after the easyui library when I include jquery first the problem is solved.